# Post list field In urllib3

Tags: python, urllib3

I'm creating a simple AWS lambda function to post some data to an API but the API expects a list however I can't get it to work. I've got the following code that I'm testing with

```py
import urllib3
import json

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
file_path = 'file.png'
with open(file_path, 'rb') as fp:
  file_data = fp.read()

payload = {
  'from': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'file': ('file.png', file_data),
}

r = http.request(
  'POST',
  'http://httpbin.org/post',
  fields=payload
)

json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
```

But this returns an error about expecting the field to be a certain type and basically not being allowed to be a list which is fine, but how can I make this work.

I'm connecting to a Rails based server, and in order for a form-encoded form submission to be a list, I need to send multiple params with a name containing `[]` on the end, but of course if I try creating a dict with multiple keys the same, it'll just ignore them all so I'm not really sure how to handle this.

I'm pretty new to python so sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here, one is posting multiple values of the same key and the other is posting form data with file data in one request using `urllib3`.

You can use tuples to resolve the first problem and use `urllib3.fields.RequestField` to resolve the second problem like this:

```
"""
Following https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.fields.html
"""
import urllib3
from urllib3.fields import RequestField

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
FILE_PATH = 'file.png'
with open(FILE_PATH, 'rb') as file_handle:
    file_data = file_handle.read()
fields = []
request_field = RequestField(name='file', data=file_data, filename=FILE_PATH)
content_disposition = f'form-data; size={len(file_data)}'
request_field.make_multipart(content_disposition=content_disposition, content_type='image/png')
fields.append(request_field)
fields.append(('from[]', 'a'))
fields.append(('from[]', 'b'))
fields.append(('from[]', 'c'))
response = http.request(
    'POST',
    'http://httpbin.org/post',
    fields=fields
)
print(response.data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Note multiple values for the same key are added as multiple tuples, not a list.

The output (with the image as a single pixel png) is:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {
    "file": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAAA1BMVEUAAACnej3aAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAApJREFUCNdjYAAAAAIAAeIhvDMAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
  }, 
  "form": {
    "from[]": [
      "a", 
      "b", 
      "c"
    ]
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity", 
    "Content-Length": "537", 
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=e6441032102e8f3fc564107bcd9ea02f", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-urllib3/1.26.9", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-64447758-4cbca2b82c1917ff5a8cebc7"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

I took the liberty of renaming some of your variables following Pylint Predefined Naming Styles.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect thank you! I knew I couldn't just send a list of values for a given field, the error was quite clear about that and a discussion on GitHub confirmed it but I couldn't make heads of tails of the documentation, but this is spot on!